# Problems with Spork & Rspec in rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rubymine, spork

Trying to use Rspec with Spork in RubyMine;

Gemfile:

```
gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
```

.rspec:

```
--color
--drb
```

[spec_helper.rb](https://gist.github.com/XimikS/4755344).

```
$ spork rspec


Using RSpec, Unknown
  -- Starting to fill pool...
     Wait until at least one slave is provided before running tests...
  ** CTRL+BREAK to stop Spork and kill all ruby slave processes **
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
  -- Rinda Ring Server listening for connections...

   -- build slave 1...
   -- build slave 2...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
  --> DRb magazine_slave_service: 1 provided...
  --> DRb magazine_slave_service: 2 provided...
```

(Rspec, **Unknown**?! WTF)
And.. nothing more in output. How to run specs?

What I'm doing wrong? =)

Comment: What did you expect it to do? I don't see any error. Spork just speeds up the tests.

Comment: I don't know how to run Rspec now :D
 Trying to run Rspec in other windows fails because of access to db is already busy (by spork, obviously)

Comment: it "fails"? is there any particular exception? Please add the relevant information, right now we only see that you got spork running.

Comment: I think it's because you're running it with "spork rspec". In one terminal you should run only "spork", and in another you can run rspec with "rspec spec".

Comment: Baboon, `rake aborted!
Permission denied - db/test.sqlite3
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Comment: ctshryock, I don't want to use Guard, RubyMine already includes this functionality.

Comment: zigomir, I tryed, nothing changed, got the same error as in previous comment.

Comment: In rubymine you can use CTRL+SHIFT+A then type "spork".

Comment: @Baboon, mmm, I know. What's next?=)

Comment: It seems to be a database authorization issue. Your tests are running fine without spork?

Comment: @Baboon , yes, everything ok.

Comment: @Baboon, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: I've never faced this scenario, and I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what could be wrong with spork. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody. Problem solved. My mistake, need to use `$ rspec ..` instead of `$ rake spec`